# IOS add button to custom UIVIEW

Tags: ios

I am trying to have a modal pop up view that has a login button.
But when I click on the login button.
I am getting unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1a846c when clicking the login button.

```
loginView.opaque = NO;
loginView.autoresizingMask =
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[aSuperview addSubview:loginView];

//login button
const CGFloat DEFAULT_BUTTON_WIDTH = 280.0;
const CGFloat DEFAULT_BUTTON_HEIGHT = 50.0;
const float fbYoffset=150.0;
CGRect fbButtonFrame = CGRectMake(0, fbYoffset, DEFAULT_BUTTON_WIDTH, DEFAULT_BUTTON_HEIGHT);
UIButton *fbLoginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[fbLoginButton setFrame:fbButtonFrame];

[fbLoginButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Login",nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
fbLoginButton.autoresizingMask =
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

[fbLoginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(login) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[loginView addSubview:fbLoginButton];



-(void)login
{
    NSLog(@"Pressed login..");
}
```

Comment: Do you have your method login in your .h file ?

Comment: There must be some other code that is not being shown here. What you show is the button properly having a target/action set, using "self" as the target, and you do show a login method, thus the only possible solution is that "self" is not where the method "login" is defined.

Comment: David, sorry. I don't get what you meant.